# Cucumber will not set up in intelliJ - does not seem to recognise Gherkin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber, pom.xml

I am trying to very basically install and set up cucumber in intelliJ with Java but it will not work. I have added/enabled the cucumber for Java plugin, I've added the maven dependency for cucumber, but when I create a .feature file, it does not create a Cucumber file as it should. The little logo next to the file does not change to the Cucumber icon. The feature file kind of half reads the syntax correct, when I type 'feature:' or 'scenario:' it turns orange however it doesn't when I type 'Given', 'When' etc. Can anyone shed some light on why it might be doing this?

See photos of pom and feature file:

[image]
[image]

Please help I'm at my wits end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change [filetype in Intellij IDEA](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206237949-Change-file-association-manually)